# How to test a code which uses ini_get with different ini values dynamically with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, automated-tests

I have a code that uses `ini_get` and does some additional logic based on its value.

I want to test the code using PHPUnit with multiple set of values for those ini-configuration. Is that possible? How?

A mimic of the code is as below:

```
function check_upload_limit()
{
    $value = ini_get('post_max_size');

    if (num_bytes($value) < 10 * 1000 * 1000)
    {
        return 'Too small';
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Sufficient';
    }
}
```

I want to test it with several values for `post_max_size`.

Answer (score 0):

### **Don't**

Create a method to encapsulate retrieving ini_get and returning the result.
Then mock that method and it's return value in your tests.

For your specific example, replace the line `$value = ini_get('post_max_size');` with `$value = $this->getPostMaxSize();` where getPostMaxSize() will simply return ini_get('post_max_size')